# How to display the Attachment(picture) on the list item page?

Tags: sharepoint-list

I want to display my attached images on my list in SharePoint, However, right now I have to open the attachment, copy the URL and paste in under pictures to display it. Is there a way to display the pictures automatically?

Comment: What kind of SharePoint do you use? SPO, Server 2007, 2010, etc.? Do you want to display them on Display Form of list item?

Comment: The Newest sharepoint in office 365. yes I would like to display the attachments under the pictures column

Comment: You cannot do that without JS Link or Client Side Rendering. I am not a expert in it but this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Can someone write a Json code under column formatting to have the attachment's URL directly transfer to the picture column?